# how generate & use list of values within a commend?

Tags: windows, shell, cmd

I would like to use a windows command that is processing many files.
The syntax of the command is as follows & requires a separated list of filenames: `command "file_1 file_2 file_3 file_4" output-file`

I have to handle 1000s of files.
Is there any way generate the list of files automatically in the command line?
Something like:

```
command "(echo file_1.txt to file_1000.txt)" output-file
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Does `command` support wildcards? Regard that there is a limit of 8K characters/bytes of the command line length…

Comment: The issue is, that the command does not support wildcards, CMD does not allow nested commands as Unix (here it would be "{$echo dir/*.txt}" & that the length of the command is limited.
Would it be possible to read a file list from a text file into a variable %f & put the variable %f in the command, e.g. command " %f " output?

Comment: That would not change anything, because also variable lengths are limited to 8K, and even `for` meta-variables like `%f` cannot receive longer values…

Answer (score 0):

If your question is "how do I create a list of files numbered 1 to 1000," then you can do this in PowerShell:

```
1..1000 | % { New-Item file_$_.txt }
```

Note that `%` is an alias for `ForEach-Object`. The `$_` token means "current object from the pipeline" (i.e., the number 1-1000).

Answer (score 0):

This question has many open-ended issues. It is unlikely that all files can be processed by a single command since `cmd` has a line length limit. However, you can process them one at a time. It is unclear what the `output-file` would contain.

```
FOR %A IN ("file_*") DO (command "%A")
```

If this is in a .bat file script, double the PERCENT character on the variable name.

```
FOR %%A IN ("file_*") DO (command "%%~A")
```